# CloudKit - How to share a set of entities and allow creation of new data

Tags: core-data, cloudkit

I'm currently building up an app for grocery-shopping where I'd want to share a set of data (shops, products, recipes and tags) within the family.

Let's say I have Entities called `Shop`, `Product`, `Recipe` and `Tag`. How can I establish an relation in CloudKit, that allows each invited user to edit shops, add products or read recipes?

I want to share all known information inside something kind of a "family store" but it seems like there's no documentation on how to do this using CloudKit and CoreData, so I hope for someone who already build sharing of a set of entities between multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest setting up a `Family` entity in CloudKit, alongside your `Shop`, `Product`, `Recipe`, and `Tag` entities. The `Family` would be the **parent entity**, and the others would have a `CKReference` property that points to a `Family` record.

In order to coordinate sharing records between users, you could look at `CKShare` which is the mechanism Apple provides for sharing records from the private database ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckshare)).

In your case, you would share `Family` records between users. As long as the other records are set to have the `Family` record as its parent, they will automatically be shared along with the `Family` record's `CKShare`.

There is a tutorial that I like on Medium that walks through how it works which should apply pretty well to what you are trying to do: https://medium.com/@adammillers/cksharing-step-by-step-33800c8950d2

The whole workflow is more than you can shove into a Stack Overflow answer. I hope this helps get you started.